# Load Balanced Application Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, service-application

What exactly load balanced application server means?

Suppose I have one application server on which State Service Application is running. Now if I join another application server on farm and start State Service Application on that new machine, then it becomes load balanced?
Because now same service application is running on two servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. When you start the service ( Manage Services on sever) to multiple Servers then SharePoint automatically detect it and load balanced.

I.e you configure the User profile services, now you run the User Profile Services on both server( from manage services on server), so if one server goes down, SharePoint will automatically get the services from 2nd server.

Comment: We checked same for Central admin. Site is hosted on App1 and App2 but when we are clicking on SharePoint Central Admin link in Start menu then it is browsing the App1 CA only. If App1 is down then App2 should be browsable. is it possible?